# Why does comparing the result of scanf() with NULL generate a compiler warning?

Tags: c, input, null, scanf

I'm writing in C and I need to read everything that arrives in input but I don't know how many characters I will receive. I wrote

```
while (scanf("%c", &read) != NULL)
```

but the compiler tells me: `[Warning] comparison between pointer and integer`, so what should I write instead?

Comment: scanf returns integer

Comment: And don't use scanf. It points out that you are total beginner.

Comment: Don't confuse `NULL`, which in C is a pointer, with integer zero, or with `EOF` which is also an integer.

Comment: @cdarke "`NULL`, which in C is a pointer," --> `NULL`, as a _null pointer constant_,  unfortunately, may be an _integer_ or a pointer.  In OP's case, it is a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead, of `scanf("%c", &read)` you may consider [`read = getc(stdin)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc).

Please, be aware that `getc()`/`fgetc()` return `int`.

This allows to store any character as number in range [0, 255] as well as to return `EOF` (usually -1) in case of failure.

So, with `getc()` it would look like:

```
int read;
while ((read = getc(stdin)) != EOF)
```

Note:

You may assign `read` to a variable of type `char` – it will be implicitly converted. In case of `getc()` succeeded, there shouldn't be any data loss in this implicit conversion.

---

A little sample to show this at work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  enum { N = 10 };
  char buffer[N];
  /* read characters and print if buffer ful */
  int read, n = 0;
  while ((read = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    if (n == N) {
      printf("%.*s", N, buffer); n = 0;
    }
    buffer[n++] = read;
  }
  /* print rest if buffer not empty */
  if (n > 0) printf("%.*s", n, buffer);
  /* done */
  return 0;
}
```

Note:

The read characters are stored in `buffer` without a termination `'\0'`. This is handled in `printf()` respectively by the formatter `%.*s` meaning string with max. width `*` where width and string are read as consecutive arguments.

<kbd>[**Live Demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/MVUR54)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
scanf("%c", &read) != NULL
```

is a typing mistake : the types of left and right operands to `!=` don't match. Read about [type systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system).

Read the [documentation of `scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). It says that `scanf` returns some `int` value.

But `NULL` is a pointer value (it is `(void*)0`).

How can a pointer be meaningfully compared to an `int`? On my Debian/x86-64, they don't even have the same size (as returned by `sizeof`): a pointer takes 8 bytes but an `int` takes 4 bytes.

So the compiler is right in warning you.

You probably want to code instead  something like `while (scanf("%c", &read) >0)` or  even `while (scanf("%c", &read) == 1)` since for a successful scan of `"%c"` the `scanf` function is documented to give 1.

Of course, in that particular case, using `fgetc` is better (more readable, and probably slightly faster). Read [documentation of `fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) and follow the advice given by [Sheff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52234068/841108).

Next time:

- be sure to **read the documentation** of *every* function that you are using. Never use a function whose documentation you have not read and understood.
- ask the compiler to give all warnings and debug info, so with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Trust your compiler, and **improve your code to get no warnings at all**.
- read [*How To Debug Small Programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).
- read the [documentation of `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) (and perhaps of [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)).
- study, for inspiration, the source code of some small [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) similar to yours (perhaps on [github](http://github.com/)).

PS. Naming your variable `read` is poor taste. For most people it conflicts with the [POSIX `read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) function.