# Segmentation fault (core dumped) appears when C code is run on Linux machine

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

If the C code is run on windows machine using visual studio, the segmentation doesnt show up and the output is also as expected. 
Note: There is lot of usage of pointers in the code for memory allocation and deallocation. The depth of usage of pointers is high (upto 3 levels).
What could be the problem?? The debugging of C code in gdb is also very difficult as it just shows which function is throwing the seg fault and not the line in the code.

Comment: You are most likely invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: 100% UB like out of bonds read or access unitialized pointers. It may work or not as it an U*ndefined* B*ehavior*

Comment: Compile your code with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Without any [MCVE] your question is unclear. Consider also using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). See also the hints given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52235240/841108), they are relevant for you also

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really provided enough information. People here will need more information, to be able to help you. I will update the answer if more details are available.

This is pretty much you can do as of now.

1. Try to narrow down the problem, and post it here. Certainly, you have limited experience with C, which is okay. But while you may not realise, the details you have given about your program, like "lot of usage" of pointers, or "pointer of pointer of pointer"(3 level), etc, apply to each and every real world C program. Look for the functions where you see segfault.
2. Are you sure about your conclusion of `it works on windows, but not linux`. Or it's just an intermittent failure(works/fails sometimes randomly). Try running it multiple times with different inputs(if possible) on both windows & linux to be sure.
3. Post some details like which compiler you are using on Windows vs Linux. In my experience, I have seen string allocations working differently with different compilers.
4. Try to post a reproducible piece of code if possible, a small piece of code from your program, that can run independently, and shows similar error. Or at least post the section of code and stack trace of the seg fault. That is how people will have most probability to be able to help you.
5. If your program is generating a core file on segmentation fault, learn about how to analyse it using gdb, if you haven't done it already. It provides pretty detailed information. In case core file is not getting generated, or it's incomplete/corrupted. Run `ulimit -c unlimited` on terminal before starting your program, or put this line in ~/.bashrc file.
6. Learn how to use `valgrind`. Run your program with valgrind, and see if the generated report shows and `invalid reads` or `invalid writes`. Rule of thumb is, you shouldn't be having any of those, unless you are absolutely sure, after getting reviewed, that it's there for a reason. Most of the times, there is always a better way to avoid it. Any such error will either lead you to your issue, or another future issue.

Comment: The advice about getting a core dump is mis-guided -- the OP is already looking at the problem with GDB, he doesn't need a core dump. The advice to compile with debugging info (already given in comments) is missing, and is likely the *key* to finding the problem.

Comment: I suggested that to ensure, that he is not just trying to reproduce the issue with GDB, but is also backtracking the already generated core dump. As many multi-threading issues don't come up while just running the code with GDB. But I agree, it was valid only if my assumption is correct.
And yes, I missed the compiling with warnings enabled.